# how to define angular 6 route for multiple level path

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular6

I want to define multiple level route in angular 6, this is what I need:

for first level routes, I have:

```
dashboardRoutes:Routes=[
    {
        path: "dashboard",
        component: DashobardComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children:[
            {
                path: 'user', component: UserComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'overview', component:OverViewComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

But now, I want to have overview to have their own child, so I defined html as:

```
<div>This is overvew</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And then I defined overview routes like below:

```
    const overviewRoutes:Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: OverViewComponent,
        children:[
            {
                path:'reg',
                component: RegularComponent
            },
            {
                path:'rt',
                component: RealTimeComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

then I got error:

```
 Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashboard/overview/reg'
```

Now, I am lost, overView is already defined in the second route, how should I update first route here?

I changed first one to

path: 'overview', redirectTo:'overview/reg', totally failed.

I could define all the routes in the first route definition, but that is not elegant enough at all.  I want the overview route definition in its own module here.

Hope you understand what I mean here.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
const overviewRoutes:Routes = [
{
    path: "dashboard/overview", // <-- missed this
    component: OverViewComponent,
    children:[
        {
            path:'reg',
            component: RegularComponent
        },
        {
            path:'rt',
            component: RealTimeComponent
        }
    ]
}
```

];

Anguar says it cannot find the route **dashboard/overview/reg**, because you didn't define where is **dashboard/overview**. Simply put it to path of the first component.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just have an empty path for the `OverViewComponent`:

```
const overviewRoutes:Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: OverViewComponent,
        children:[
            {
                path:'reg',
                component: RegularComponent
            },
            {
                path:'anotherPage',
                component: anotherPageComponent
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

agree with Chrillewoodz's solution. 
Also, it is good to put 'review' component and it's children into a feature module. In there you can define route file for this feature module.

see official Angular document [here](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules), and also Deborah Kurata's Angular router topic talk in [this year's NgConf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ)

Comment: I tested using @chrillewoodz solution, not working, please see my updated contents

Comment: if you've already defined a review module and its own route file, make sure you register the route using 'forChild' command in the module file: imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],